# Extract part of string: date and times

Tags: r, regex, date, datetime, stringr

I have a variable that usually has some gibberish like:

`\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tSeuat eselyt\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tti 30.07.2019 klo 12:00 - 14:30\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTau ski 2342342 2342342\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n`

I am trying to extract the date (30.07.2019) and time (12:00 - 14:30). I am not very good with parsing so some help with implementing this in R would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rely on the fact that the date and time part only occur once in your data you could use regular expressions to extract them (here using a dataframe):

```
library(tidyverse)
data <-
   tibble(gibberish_string = "\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tSeuat eselyt\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tti 30.07.2019 klo 12:00 - 14:30\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTau ski 2342342 2342342\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n")

data %>% mutate(date = str_extract(gibberish_string,
                                   pattern = "\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}"),
                time = str_extract(gibberish_string,
                                   pattern = "\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}"))
```

Comment: I like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

String split, then extract date and times:

```
x <- "\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tSeuat eselyt\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tti 30.07.2019 klo 12:00 - 14:30\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTau ski 2342342 2342342\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n"

lapply(strsplit(x, "[\n\t ]"), function(i){
  dd <- i[ grepl("[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}", i) ]
  tt <- i[ grepl("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", i) ]
  c(dd, paste(tt, collapse = "-"))
})

# [[1]]
# [1] "30.07.2019"  "12:00-14:30"
```

Answer (score 1):

This for date:

```
(\d{1,2}[\.\/]){2}((\d{4})|(\d{2}))
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGYjIZ/1)

This for time:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s?-\s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGYjIZ/3)

Comment: This is semi ok as I dont understand how to implement in R.

Answer (score 1):

A kind of lengthy step by step `base`/`stringr` approach:

```
tst<-"\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tSeuat eselyt\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tti 30.07.2019 klo 12:00 - 14:30\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTau ski 2342342 2342342\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n"
 cleaner<-gsub("\\n|\\t","",tst)
 split_txt<-strsplit(cleaner, "\\s(?=[a-z])",perl=T)
 dates<-stringr::str_extract_all(unlist(split_txt),
                         "\\d{1,}\\.\\d{2,}\\.\\d{4}")
 times<-stringr::str_extract_all(stringr::str_remove_all(unlist(split_txt),
                          "[A-Za-z]"),".*\\-.*")
 dates[lengths(dates)>0]
[[1]]
[1] "30.07.2019"

 trimws(times[lengths(times)>0])
[1] "12:00 - 14:30"
```